# Press CTRL+ALT+DEL, blank screen for 2 mins, Press CTRL+ALT+DEL, repeat

Tags: windows-7, login, hotkeys, delay

Has anyone experienced an issue where the password prompt never appears after hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>?  This happens about 30% of the time when I start or try to unlock my computer.  The only resolution is to turn the machine off and hope that it doesn’t happen the next time.  If my computer was locked, this means I lose any unsaved work in programs that can’t auto-recover.

Exciting video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBCLxwHtrY

Comment: Are you on a domain?

Comment: Is this a wireless keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a bug in the McAfee endpoint encryption that was specific to my chipset. A software update resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Try it in Safe Mode.  If it doesn't happen then it's probably a piece of software (either an 
  application or a non-essential driver) that's causing the delay.

If it does appear to be a piece of software, you can use MSConfig and/or [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to selectively start enabling/disabling startup stuff, to hopefully hammer down the culprit.

- Try [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to go back to a date/point before this started happening.
- Try creating another user and see if it behaves the same way.
- Try unplugging any/all peripheral devices (printers, joysticks, mp3 players, etc.) and see if it reacts any differently.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the problem go away would be to set the option "Interactive logon: Do not require <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>."

From the Local Group Policy Editor description:

> This security setting determines whether pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> is
>   required before a user can log on.
>
> If this policy is enabled on a computer, a user is not required to
>   press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to log on. Not having to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> leaves
>   users susceptible to attacks that attempt to intercept the users'
>   passwords. Requiring <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> before users log on ensures that
>   users are communicating by means of a trusted path when entering their
>   passwords.
>
> If this policy is disabled, any user is required to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>
>   before logging on to Windows (unless they are using a smart card for
>   Windows logon).
>
> Default on domain-computers: Disabled. Default on stand-alone
>   computers: Enabled.

To enable this, run GPEDIT.MSC. Under Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options, find "Interactive logon: Do not require <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>." Set the value to "Enabled" and the logon screen will display the user/password prompt without needing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>.

Alternatively, using your favorite NOTEPAD-like editor, create a file called DisableCAD.reg (or something similar) and place in it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"DisableCAD"=dword:00000001
```

Once you have the file, you can "run" it by just double-clicking on it. You will be prompted to apply the change to your registry. Answer yes and (possibly after a reboot) no more <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> problem.

You can always set it back by changing the "1" to a "0" and reapplying it to the registry.